# Using "timeIntervalSinceNow" in a predicate in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, nspredicate, cloudkit

I am trying to query for records that are created in the last 1 hour using Cloudkit (in SWIFT)

I have tried:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(predicateWithFormat : "timeIntervalSinceNow %@ < %f", "creationTime", -3600)
```

without success. The error message refers to a parsing error.

Anyone has a clue what would be the right format?

n.b `creationTime` is the name of the field in the Table

Comment: Are you trying to do this with Core Data, or an array of `NSDate` instances?

Comment: trying to do this on CloudKit data. I think it has the same exact object and syntax with CoreData

Comment: Then you are highly unlikely to get it to work as the dates in the store won't understand `timeIntervalSinceNow`, you need to just use < but with a calculated date to compare to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your predicate isn't valid. Take a look at [Apple's guide for creating NSPredicates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html).

You should use a [key path](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-183455) on the left hand side of the expression. I assume that you have an array of objects, and these objects have a property named `creationTime`. Then the predicate should look like this:

```
NSPredicate(format: "creationTime.timeIntervalSinceNow > %d", -3600)
```

Note that I have used "greater than" `>` operator instead of `<` in the predicate you posted. That's because a date from the past will return a negative value from `timeIntervalSinceNow` method, as [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceNow) states.

EDIT: 
Seems you can't use key paths in CloudKit predicates. But I think you can create a reference date (an hour ago) and use it for comparison predicate:

```
let now = NSDate()
if let anHourAgo = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
    .HourCalendarUnit,
    value: -1,
    toDate: now,
    options: NSCalendarOptions(0)) {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "creationDate > %@", anHourAgo)
        let filtered = records.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate!)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am doing this on cloudKit data, which I guess has a different syntax than if your were doing this on NSArray. Apple's guide is unfortunately not providing the syntax for Swift.

Comment: Then please edit your question and add the information about using CloudKit. Anyway, predicate syntax is available in `CKQuery` class reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQuery_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014043-CH1-SW9. The predicate format string syntax should be exactly the same for Swift and Objective-C.

Comment: I've added another way of creating a predicate. It should work with CloudKit, however I haven't tested it as I don't want to set up a full CloudKit project just for that.

Comment: Thank you. Made it work with your format - with a slight tweak though.